# Arduino compiler failing with error code - invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript

Tags: c++, arrays, indexing, compiler-errors, arduino

Quite a bit of untested code but the only thing really concerning me at the moment is my `DISPLAY` variable. I don't see how it is much different than my `FONT` array (which works fine) yet `DISPLAY` is the one that gets 'invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript' I should be able to index an array of integers with integers (at least I have been with `FONT`).

```
#include <WiFiNINA.h>
#include <NTPClient.h>
#include <WiFiUdp.h>

#include "font.h"

const int PIXEL_WIDTH = 30;
const int PIXEL_HEIGHT = 5;

int DISPLAY[PIXEL_HEIGHT][PIXEL_WIDTH] = {};

bool MILI_TIME = false;

String FORMATTING[2] = {"LONGS","SHORTH:LONGM"};

char ssid[] = "REMOVED";                 // your network SSID (name) between the " "
char pass[] = "REMOVED";  // your network password between the " "
int keyIndex = 0;                 // your network key Index number (needed only for WEP)
int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;      // connection status
WiFiServer server(80);            // server socket



WiFiClient client = server.available();

WiFiUDP ntpUDP;
NTPClient timeClient(ntpUDP);

int ledPin = LED_BUILTIN;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  while (!Serial); // dont do anything until there is a serial connection
  
  enable_WiFi();
  connect_WiFi();

  server.begin();
  printWifiStatus();
  timeClient.begin();
  timeClient.setTimeOffset(-14400);

}

void loop() {
  timeClient.update();
  client = server.available();
  if (client) {
    printWEB();
  }
  preRender();
}

void preRender(){
  String FILLED_FORMATTING[2] = FORMATTING;
  for(int i=0;i<2;i++){  
    FILLED_FORMATTING[i].replace("LONGH",leadWithZero(timeHours()));
    FILLED_FORMATTING[i].replace("LONGM",leadWithZero(timeMinutes()));
    FILLED_FORMATTING[i].replace("LONGS",leadWithZero(timeSeconds()));
    FILLED_FORMATTING[i].replace("SHORTH",timeHours());
    FILLED_FORMATTING[i].replace("SHORTM",timeMinutes());
    FILLED_FORMATTING[i].replace("SHORTS",timeSeconds());
  }
  int x = 0;
  for(int i=0;i<FILLED_FORMATTING[0].length();i++){
    int c_ID = charID(FILLED_FORMATTING[0][i]);
    if(c_ID < 38){
      for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
        DISPLAY[j][x] = FONT[c_ID][j][0];
        x += 1;
        DISPLAY[j][x] = FONT[c_ID][j][1];
        x += 1;
        DISPLAY[j][x] = FONT[c_ID][j][2];
        x += 1;
        if(i != FILLED_FORMATTING[0].length()){
          DISPLAY[j][x] = 0;
          x += 1;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  x = PIXEL_WIDTH-1;
  for(int i=FILLED_FORMATTING[1].length()-1;i>=0;i--){
    int c_ID = charID(FILLED_FORMATTING[1][i]);
    if(c_ID < 38){
      for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
        DISPLAY[j][x] = FONT[c_ID][j][0];
        x -= 1;
        DISPLAY[j][x] = FONT[c_ID][j][1];
        x -= 1;
        DISPLAY[j][x] = FONT[c_ID][j][2];
        x -= 1;
        if(i != 0){
          DISPLAY[j][x] = 0;              //<----------- compiler error here, and ofc all instances above
          x -= 1;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

int charID(char c){
  for(int i=0;i<FONT_ID.length();i++){
    if(FONT_ID[i] == c){
      return i;
    }
  }
  return 40;
}

String timeHours(){
  if(MILI_TIME){
    return String(timeClient.getHours());
  }
  else{
    return convFromMili(timeClient.getHours());
  }
}

String timeMinutes(){
  return String(timeClient.getMinutes());
}

String timeSeconds(){
  return String(timeClient.getSeconds());
}

String leadWithZero(String t){
  if(t.length() < 2){
    t = "0"+t;
    return t;
  }
}

String convFromMili(int t){
  if(t > 12){
    t -= 12;
  }else if(t == 0){
    t += 12;
  }
  String ts = String(t);
  return ts;
}

void printWifiStatus() {
  // print the SSID of the network you're attached to:
  Serial.print("SSID: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.SSID());

  // print your board's IP address:
  IPAddress ip = WiFi.localIP();
  Serial.print("IP Address: ");
  Serial.println(ip);

  // print the received signal strength:
  long rssi = WiFi.RSSI();
  Serial.print("signal strength (RSSI):");
  Serial.print(rssi);
  Serial.println(" dBm");

  Serial.print("To see this page in action, open a browser to http://");
  Serial.println(ip);
}

void enable_WiFi() {
  // check for the WiFi module:
  if (WiFi.status() == WL_NO_MODULE) {
    Serial.println("Communication with WiFi module failed!");
    // don't continue
    while (true);
  }

  String fv = WiFi.firmwareVersion();
  if (fv < "1.0.0") {
    Serial.println("Please upgrade the firmware");
  }
}

void connect_WiFi() {
  while (status != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print("Attempting to connect to SSID: ");
    Serial.println(ssid);
    status = WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
    delay(10000);
  }
}

void printWEB() {

  if (client) {                             // if you get a client,
    Serial.println("new client");           // print a message out the serial port
    String currentLine = "";                // make a String to hold incoming data from the client
    while (client.connected()) {            // loop while the client's connected
      if (client.available()) {             // if there's bytes to read from the client,
        char c = client.read();             // read a byte, then
        Serial.write(c);                    // print it out the serial monitor
        if (c == '\n') {                    // if the byte is a newline character

          // if the current line is blank, you got two newline characters in a row.
          // that's the end of the client HTTP request, so send a response:
          if (currentLine.length() == 0) {

            // HTTP headers always start with a response code (e.g. HTTP/1.1 200 OK)
            // and a content-type so the client knows what's coming, then a blank line:
            client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
            client.println("Content-type:text/html");
            client.println();
           
            //create the buttons
            client.print(WiFi.getTime());
            client.print("<br>");
            client.print(timeClient.getEpochTime());
            client.print("<br>");
            client.print(timeClient.getFormattedTime());
            client.print("<br>");
            client.print(timeClient.getDay());
            client.print("<br>");
            client.print(timeClient.getHours());
            client.print("<br>");
            client.print(timeClient.getMinutes());
            client.print("<br>");
            client.print(timeClient.getSeconds());
            client.print("<br>");
            client.print("<div style=\"display:block;padding-left:calc(50% - 150px);margin-bottom:50px\"><a href=\"/H\" style=\"text-decoration: none;color:black;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;\"><div style=\"background-color:#e3e3e3;width:300px;height:120px;font-size:50px;text-align:center;padding-top:50px\">ON</div></a></div>");
            client.print("<div style=\"display:block;padding-left:calc(50% - 150px)\"><a href=\"/L\" style=\"text-decoration: none;color:black;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;\"><div style=\"background-color:#e3e3e3;width:300px;height:120px;font-size:50px;text-align:center;padding-top:50px\">OFF</div></a></div>");
           
            
            

            // The HTTP response ends with another blank line:
            client.println();
            // break out of the while loop:
            break;
          }
          else {      // if you got a newline, then clear currentLine:
            currentLine = "";
          }
        }
        else if (c != '\r') {    // if you got anything else but a carriage return character,
          currentLine += c;      // add it to the end of the currentLine
        }

        if (currentLine.endsWith("GET /H")) {
        digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);        
        }
        if (currentLine.endsWith("GET /L")) {
        digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);       
        }
        if (currentLine.endsWith("%VAL")) {
          // Trim 'GET /' and '%VAL'
          currentLine.remove(0,5);
          currentLine.remove(currentLine.indexOf("%"),4);
          Serial.println(currentLine);
          Serial.println();
          
        }

      }
    }
    // close the connection:
    client.stop();
    Serial.println("client disconnected");
  }
}
```

`font.h`:

```
int FONT[37][5][3] = {{{1,1,1},{1,0,1},{1,0,1},{1,0,1},{1,1,1},},{{1,1,0},{0,1,0},{0,1,0},{0,1,0},{1,1,1},},{{1,1,1},{0,0,1},{1,1,1},{1,0,0},{1,1,1},},{{1,1,1},{0,0,1},{1,1,1},{0,0,1},{1,1,1},},{{1,0,1},{1,0,1},{1,1,1},{0,0,1},{0,0,1},},{{1,1,1},{1,0,0},{1,1,1},{0,0,1},{1,1,1},},{{1,1,1},{1,0,0},{1,1,1},{1,0,1},{1,1,1},},{{1,1,1},{0,0,1},{0,0,1},{0,0,1},{0,0,1},},{{1,1,1},{1,0,1},{1,1,1},{1,0,1},{1,1,1},},{{1,1,1},{1,0,1},{1,1,1},{0,0,1},{1,1,1},},{{1,1,1},{1,0,1},{1,1,1},{1,0,1},{1,0,1},},{{1,1,0},{1,0,1},{1,1,0},{1,0,1},{1,1,0},},{{1,1,1},{1,0,0},{1,0,0},{1,0,0},{1,1,1},},{{1,1,0},{1,0,1},{1,0,1},{1,0,1},{1,1,0},},{{1,1,1},{1,0,0},{1,1,1},{1,0,0},{1,1,1},},{{1,1,1},{1,0,0},{1,1,1},{1,0,0},{1,0,0},},{{1,1,1},{1,0,0},{1,0,1},{1,0,1},{1,1,1},},{{1,0,1},{1,0,1},{1,1,1},{1,0,1},{1,0,1},},{{1,1,1},{0,1,0},{0,1,0},{0,1,0},{1,1,1},},{{0,0,1},{0,0,1},{0,0,1},{1,0,1},{1,1,1},},{{1,0,1},{1,0,1},{1,1,0},{1,0,1},{1,0,1},},{{1,0,0},{1,0,0},{1,0,0},{1,0,0},{1,1,1},},{{1,1,1},{1,1,1},{1,0,1},{1,0,1},{1,0,1},},{{1,1,0},{1,0,1},{1,0,1},{1,0,1},{1,0,1},},{{1,1,1},{1,0,1},{1,0,1},{1,0,1},{1,1,1},},{{1,1,1},{1,0,1},{1,1,1},{1,0,0},{1,0,0},},{{1,1,1},{1,0,1},{1,0,1},{1,1,0},{0,0,1},},{{1,1,1},{1,0,1},{1,1,0},{1,0,1},{1,0,1},},{{0,1,1},{1,0,0},{0,1,0},{0,0,1},{1,1,0},},{{1,1,1},{0,1,0},{0,1,0},{0,1,0},{0,1,0},},{{1,0,1},{1,0,1},{1,0,1},{1,0,1},{1,1,1},},{{1,0,1},{1,0,1},{1,0,1},{0,1,0},{0,1,0},},{{1,0,1},{1,0,1},{1,0,1},{1,1,1},{1,1,1},},{{1,0,1},{1,0,1},{0,1,0},{1,0,1},{1,0,1},},{{1,0,1},{1,0,1},{1,1,1},{0,0,1},{1,1,1},},{{1,1,1},{0,0,1},{0,1,0},{1,0,0},{1,1,1},},{{0,0,0},{0,1,0},{0,0,0},{0,1,0},{0,0,0}}};
String FONT_ID = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ:";
```

did check -

```
int D[5][30];

void setup() {
}

void loop() {
  D[0][0] = 0;
}
```

and of course its fine, so I'm just wondering where I went wrong in the mess above?

and yes there's a good bit of mess/debugging stuff

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution... don't use `DISPLAY` as a variable it seems. Changing to `DISPLAY_` fixed it, figured the variable was defined as a normal integer somewhere... just not in my code.